# How to interpret breakpad microdump from logcat on windows?

Tags: android, dump, android-instant-apps, google-breakpad

I am trying to convert my old app into an instant app. After solving many issues with the instant app project structure, I was able to make a build as a regular app that runs without issues on the testing devices (android 7.0, Armv8). However, when I tried to run the instant app on the testing devices, Google Play Services for Instant Apps stops working before the instant app has started completely and I get a breakpad microdump in Android Studio's logcat. Is there any way I can use this microdump on windows to find out at which stage the code breaks? I have googling for 2 days and I haven't found any effective means of reading this output.

Judging by the next line which is:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10d4 in tid 8292 
(foriainstantapp)
```

I believe that some resource is missing or there is a Null Pointer somewhere, but I need the stack trace from the microdump to find out where.

I will be very grateful if anybody could point out a tool for windows that can interpret this output.

Comment: adb bugreport should be useful in your case to get the crash details. You can refer this adb bugreport guide: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report.html#bugreportadb
Also refer to the basic debug information from this link:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash

Comment: Another way might be to build breakpad and use the microdump_stackwalk executable. Most likely the most complicated part would be to get usable symbol information for your program.

Comment: @Ivan incase the problem is still not solved, you can share your bugreport to [Google Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787) and they’ll take a look at it for you, just let them know which log-timestamp to look for.